# AWS php Sdk error while sending sms

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk

Iam getting an error while trying to send an sms through AWS php sdk. My script is below:

```
    require './aws-autoloader.php';

     error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

   $params = array(
'credentials' => array(
    'key' => 'my_key',
    'secret' => 'my_secret_key',
),
'region' => 'ap-south-1', // < your aws from SNS Topic region
'version' => 'latest'
 );
 $sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient($params);

 $args = array(
"SenderID" => "",
"SMSType" => "Transactional",
"Message" => "Hello World!",
"PhoneNumber" => "+919939067673"
 );

 $result = $sns->publish($args);
 echo "<pre>";
 var_dump($result);
 echo "</pre>";
```

Below is the error which i am getting:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Sns\Exception\SnsException' with message 'Error executing "Publish" on "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:   Sender `InvalidPara (truncated...) InvalidParameter (client): Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: +919939067673 is not valid to publish to -   Sender InvalidParameter Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: +919939067673 is not valid to publish to  9c89eb86-0ba4-5194-acdb-b8c03c139866  ' exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: POST https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com resulted in a 400 Bad Request` response:

Can anyone pls guide me on this. Thanx

Comment: You should *NOT* put your key and secret key in the sourcecode. It is much more secure to simply assign a suitable IAM Role to the EC2 instance, then call the SDK functions directly.

Comment: Let me check that.